# Automatic Way of Adding in <BR> Tags at the end of a Sentence

Tags: html, excel, magento

I work for a company who sell items online. We're constantly listing items on our website via Spreadhseet upload and are using Magento 1.4.

Our products have long descriptions, in which we're currently manually adding in line breaks as the end of each sentence (we're doing this in excel - each paragraph is around 15 lines).

One semi-automated method we tried was using a macoring program; ghostmouse. This half worked but proved difficult as it takes a while to perfect, and still takes a long amount of time.

I've really no idea if this is at all possible - but if anybody has any suggestions or even opinions on whether they think this is possible or not, I'd be massively grateful.

Thanks For Reading, Dylan.

Comment: http://php.net/wordwrap http://php.net/nl2br

Comment: Have you tried recording an excel vba macro to add the `"<BR>"` to the end of the string?

Comment: Unless he has periods within his sentences.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you write your descriptions in excel, if you put TWO spaces between each sentence, you could write a formula like this: (assumes description is in A1)

```
=SUBSTITUTE(A1, ".  ", ".<BR>")
```

The reason I specify TWO spaces is because you might choose to use a period within your sentence that you do not want to break with a line break.

Comment: We're not writing these descriptions ourselves. They're coming directly from a supplier.

Comment: Then just use a period with one space after it and use the SUBSTITUTE method.